# Mac OS is not picking G++ installed using Homebrew

Tags: macos, xcode, homebrew

I already had Clang on my MacOS Mojave, but I installed gcc using Homebrew.

Now I see the new g++ in `/usr/local/bin/` :

```
$ /usr/local/bin/g++ --version
g++ (Homebrew GCC 9.3.0) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

When I do `which` it lists to the same location (which I want) :

```
$ which g++
/usr/local/bin/g++
```

But when I run the command `g++` it again points back to clang :

```
$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

My `PATH` setting
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin

Being a linux user I was expecting the new `g++` to be picked because `which` also points to that. How can I fix this? How can I point to the g++ instead of clang++.

Comment: I fixed it by adding `/usr/local/bin/` as suffix as well to the PATH `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/loca/bin/`. Thus I have now `/usr/local/bin` as both prefix and suffix to PATH . I was assuming the PATH is searched from first to last, but that does not see to be the case. Any better answer or clearance on this point would be appreciated.

Comment: Adding to the end should not matter. What exactly does `echo $PATH` show

Comment: This is not an endorsement, this is not an answer; this is a *comment*. That said, after some frustration w/ HomeBrew years ago, I switched to MacPorts. I find it easier to get along with.